# WPF: How to get instance of a control in code declared in a resource xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm splitting my GUI in few xaml files using resources. For the toolbar I have a xaml file (Resources/MainWindowToolbar.xaml):

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Resources="http://cansniff.com/resources">
    <ToolBar DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}" x:Key="MainWindowToolbar" 
          Background="Transparent"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          DockPanel.Dock="Left"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="8,0,0,0">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="10,0,-2,-1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="356">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="170*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="173*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Device:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.521,-0.346"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboxDevices" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="167" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnConnect" Content="Connect" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding ConnectDeviceCommand}"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnRefresh" Content="Refresh" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="49,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" Command="{Binding RefreshDevicesCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ToolBar>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in my window (MainWindow.xaml) I just merge resources:

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MainWindowMenus.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MainWindowToolbar.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

How can I get an instance of  control in my code (MainWindow.xaml.cs)?

Comment: I would say resourcedictionaries are used for shared styling and animation and such. In case you want to share a control, you should create UserControls, that can then be added to other controls / other windows. I don't see a direct usecase for your way of splitting things up

Comment: Nope, this isn't how you do it.  Use UserControls for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna answer your question, and then I'm gonna tell you why it won't work :P

To fetch an object you've declared as a Resource, you do it as follows:

```
ToolBar toolBar = FindResource("MainWindowToolbar") as ToolBar;
```

But... This probably won't work for what you're trying to do. An instance of a Control can only have one visual parent. In most cases, trying to reuse that instance for several views would either throw an exception, or result in weird behaviors.

The correct way to do this is using UserControls, or Styles and Templates. The easiest way would be creating a UserControl with your ToolBar inside, and then adding that UserControl to every view you want it to have it.

Comment: When instantiate my UserControl in the MainWindow.xaml as "<local:MainToolbarUserControl />" how I get the instance in my code  (MainWindow.xaml.cs)?

Comment: Set an `x:Name` to it, like this `<local:MainToolbarUserControl x:Name="MyToolbar" />`, and then you can access it from code-behind with that name: `MyToolbar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`